# Sorting a list of dictionaries based on one couple key-value

Tags: python, dictionary

One of the dictionary in the list is:

```
[{' School': 'GP',
  'Age': '18',
  'StudyTime': '2',
  'Failures': '0',
  'Health': '3',
  'Absences': '6',
  'G1': '5',
  'G2': '6',
  'G3': '6'}
  ………………….]
```

I want to sort them by `Age` so the output should be like:

```
Range for age is 15 to 22
{ 15 : [
         {'School': 'GP',
          'StudyTime': 4.2,
          'Failures': 3,
          'Health': 3,
          'Absences': 6,
          'G1': 7,
          'G2': 8,
          'G3': 10
         },
         { ...
           other dictionary
         },
         ...
       ],

  16 : [
         {'School': 'MS',
          'StudyTime': 1,
          'Failures': 1.2,
          'Health': 4,
          'Absences': 10,
          'G1': 9,
          'G2': 11,
          'G3': 7
         },
         { ...
           other dictionary
         },
         ...
       ],
  ...
}
```

I have tried to solve this problem with the code below, but the index for `age_list` goes out of range:

```
age_list = [15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]
#dict_list is the list of dictionaries that need to be sorted
`  res = defaultdict(list)
  for i in age_list:
     for j in dict_list:
        if age_list[i] == j['Age']:
            res[i].append(j)`
    
    print(res)
```

Comment: `dct = dct.sort(key=lambda k: k['age'])`.

Comment: replace this if age_list[i] == j['Age'] with this : if i == j['Age']

Comment: I tried if i == j['Age']  already

Answer (score 0):

Based on the expected input and output, it appears that there are three tasks involved:

1. Digit strings should be converted to integers when possible (e.g., `"15"` should become `15`).
2. Dictionary entries should be collated based on the `"Age"` key.
3. In the sorted result, each entry should no longer have the `"Age"` key.

Below is a function that receives a single dictionary entry and performs the first task.

```py
def process_dictionary(dictionary):
    result = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        # might want to use .isnumeric or .isdecimal instead
        if value.isdigit():
            result[key] = int(value)
    return result
```

The second and third tasks can be achieved by slightly modifying your original code.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def collate_by_age(entries):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for entry in entries:
        # pop (remove) "Age" key from entry
        age = entry.pop("Age")
        # append to result
        result[age].append(entry)
    return result
```

Putting these together,

```py
entries = [process_dictionary(dictionary) for dictionary in dictionaries]
result = collate_by_age(entries)
```

If you're only interested in a specific set of ages, e.g., from 15 to 22, you can simply loop over the `result` dictionary.

```py
target_age = {age: result[age] for age in range(15, 23)}
```